# How to choose the MIN of a calculated column (not in Power Query)

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop

Working with basketball data, I'm trying to get the time on court for the players (there are some columns that have information about a player or players).

I tried to obtain the value with a calculated column, named "TimeOnCourt". The code works for most cases but there is a case that, due to a mistake in the data entry team, there are different values of the players columns for the same "TimeOnCourt" so, when I try to visualize the information, the data entry mistake comes out.

I guess I could use the column "Index" to add a piece of code to choose the MIN value for the "TimeOnCourt" column but, after trying some options, I don't know where to put it or if I have to change the full code.

I also tried with Test_Flags but not working for all cases (but could fix 2 of the 4 cases).

Add you the link with the pbix file and the Test_Flag measures I tried: [Link to pbix file v3](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SlzwO6bgBBgrftwrVPGRVBE9KkIy_YqJ)

And the image with the mistake marked. The expected time in the right visualization should be 0:40:00 instead of 0:43:03 (it's due to the duplicate in Full Quarter = 2Q and Time_Def = 0:04:00. This could happen again although I talked with them so the solution should be general, not filtering this specific case.

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kehdx.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Added the pbix file with the code of the measures and the dataset, to help the community to test the problem.

Comment: Your question should be of general interest and self-contained, not requiring external sources. But it rather looks like an unpaid consulting job.